# How to use Gitlab CI depends-on on jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file and there are couple of jobs I need to run, but **THERE'S AN ORDER** I need them to run.

But in the current setup, order is not preserved. They Happen randomly.

I have **ONE** `stage` and **TWO** `jobs`. Both jobs uses the same stage.

```
stages:
  - PREREQUISITES

prerequisites-install:
  stage: PREREQUISITES
  script:
    - echo "hi"
    - yum update --exclude=google-cloud-sdk -y && sudo yum install wget unzip -y

create-ssh-key-pair:
  stage: PREREQUISITES
  script:
    - pwd
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
```

The order I want is:

```
run prerequisites-install and then run create-ssh-key-pair

prerequisites-install -> create-ssh-key-pair
```

But when pipeline runs, the actual flow is

```
create-ssh-key-pair -> prerequisites-install
```

How can I add a tag like `depends on` to the `create-ssh-key-pair` job so it will always wait until the `prerequisites-install` is done?

Thank you!

Comment: jobs in one stage are meant to run in parallel, that is the whole point of putting multiple jobs in one stage, create another stage if you want to fix the sequence of jobs.

Comment: I used the `resource_group` tag to sequence the jobs in the same stage.

Comment: I don't know how are you doing that but resource_group doesn't serve this purpose:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#resource_group